# Module dependency not working with a gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, game-engine, lwjgl

I'm currently working on a game engine called Maple. Now the project folder itself contains two modules. The engine, which is a gradle project so I can easily get the LWJGL3 libs and then a second module called Sandbox which is just a normal java project.

Now my goal is simple, two modules, one runs the application with the resources and the main method and the other just has the libraries, classes and interfaces that maple contains. The problem is that no matter what I do, the two modules are completely blind to one another. I tried to make both normal java projects and it worked completely fine and I was able to import a Display class from the Maple module, but when I make a gradle project it doesn't work.
I didn't even forget putting them in packages. `import com.maple.Display;` won't work even when I typed it in manually(Usually IntelliJ will auto pickup something in scope.)

I even tried running a two way dependency, and that didn't work either.

I probably don't know what the hell I'm doing, but hopefully stack can help me out here.

Comment: Why 2 modules ? can't you make a single gradle project with your maple code and put lwjgl as a dependency ?

Comment: Like I explained, one of the modules is a gradle project, with LWJGL as a dependency. That's not my problem though. My problem is that I'm looking to split the engine from any actual testing (hence the name "sandbox" of the second module). And of course, like I also said, adding the first module(Maple) as a dependency of the second one(Sandbox) isn't working. Thus my problem.